# OpenCV trackbar callback in C++ class

Tags: c++, opencv, callback, trackbar

I have a question about how to define the callback for trackbars in OpenCV when working with classes in C++.

When I define my trackbar let's say in the constructor method of my .cpp class how can I define the callback?

I have been trying to work with function pointers but it doesn't work out. I guess I must be doing something very wrong :-)

This is my header file:

```
class SliderwithImage {

public:
    SliderwithImage(void);
    ~SliderwithImage(void); 

    void sliderCallBack(int pos);
};
```

This is the implementation file:

```
#include "SliderwithImage.h"

void SliderwithImage::sliderCallBack(int pos) {


}

SliderwithImage::SliderwithImage(void)  {

    const char* windowName = "window";
    int lowvalue  =1;

    namedWindow(windowName,  CV_GUI_EXPANDED);

    createTrackbar("mytrackbar", windowName, &lowvalue, 255, sliderCallBack);

}

SliderwithImage::~SliderwithImage(void) {

}
```

Obviously the createTrackbar method does not recognize sliderCallBack... I guess it's a problem of scope. But I am not sure how to solve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the callback function either as a global function or a static member function. To make it more OOP look, you might prefer to implement it as a static member function:)

Comment: I just tried it and it works with a global function but only with the method cvCreateTrackBar not with createTrackBar. 

I am not quit getting the difference between these two but it works now.

Comment: Do you know why does it have to be global or static? What would be the problem if it were a member function (other than giving a compile error).

Comment: @user2565010, this is because when a member function is called, a hidden parameter (i.e. the "this" pointer of your class) is included in the call. In global / static member functions the this pointer is not passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 7):

The callback function must be static or global, but you can pass it a reference to an object you want to operate on (see [this post](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Member-function-callback-in-cvCreateTrackbar-td3785481.html) on the OpenCV Users mailing list).

The [createTrackbar](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/user_interface.html#cv-createtrackbar) method has a `userdata` parameter which is passed to the calling function. In C there is an undocumented  `cvCreateTrackbar2` method, defined in `highgui_c.h`, which has the same functionality:

```
CVAPI(int) cvCreateTrackbar2( const char* trackbar_name, const char* window_name,
    int* value, int count, CvTrackbarCallback2 on_change,
    void* userdata CV_DEFAULT(0));
```

These methods let you create a class with a static callback function that takes a pointer to an object of that class. You can create the trackbar like so:

```
cv:createTrackbar("Label", "Window" &variable, MAX_VAL, &MyClass::func, this);
```

The callback would look something like this:

```
void MyClass:func(int newValue, void * object) {
    MyClass* myClass = (MyClass*) object;
    // ...do stuff.
}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly update the variable yourself as long as you provided a pointer to it when creating the trackbar (as above), but if you need to process it first I suggest you set it explicitly in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different solution to obtain the slider value in a class variable (in my case to obtain chosen rotation angle of a live video stream). The `int* value` in the createTrackbar function is a public class variable which is then used within a loop (while the video is acquired, but this might messily work repeatedly redrawing a single image).

Not the best solution but it works for me.

```
cv::createTrackbar("Rotation Angle(deg)", "Preview", &rotationAngle, 
alpha_slider_max, NULL);

    for(;;)
    {
        int rotAngle = this -> rotationAngle;
        cv::Mat frame;
        cv::Mat rot_frame;
        this -> capture >> frame;
        rot_frame = rotateVideo (frame, rotAngle);  
        imshow("Preview", rot_frame);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
```